# Cannot add Google sign in to My Logins

Tags: bug, status-completed, login, google-openid, my-logins

I created my Stackoverflow account using a Verisign Open Id.
Yesterday I tried adding google as a sign in, but find it's not working.
I follow these steps
[image]

[image]

[image]

This brings me back here

[image]

My logins haven't changed.

[image]

I'm using Chrome, haven't tried any other browsers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had another account using the same email address as a credential that had no site profiles associated with it.

What happened when you added your Google credential was that we noticed that there was an existing account and attempted a merge... but because you are a high rep user, the merge got dropped into a queue for a human to review. And apparently that queue is backed up a bit right now.

I approved the merge, so you should be all set.

Comment: Thank you, you are a wonderful human being, and a credit to your ancestors :)